# Metric tensor in symmetric space

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

On [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MetricTensor.html) I found a statement:
In any symmetric space,
$${g_\alpha}^\beta={g^\beta}_\alpha=\delta_\alpha^\beta$$
and so
$$g_{\alpha\alpha}=\frac{1}{g^{\alpha\alpha}}.$$

My question is how the first implies the second. I cannot see it.

Comment: Note that the usage of the words "symmetric space" found on that page are *highly* nonstandard and confusing: Symmetric space usually means something specific in Riemannian geometry (a space that possesses a geodesic-reverses involution at every point).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
{g_\alpha}^\beta={g^\beta}_\alpha=\delta_\alpha^\beta
$$
holds in *any* space, symmetric or not.

Moreover, the equation
$$
g_{\alpha\alpha}=\frac{1}{g^{\alpha\alpha}}.
$$
holds if and only if $g_{\mu\nu}$ is diagonal.